# Приветствую, подскажите как сделать чтобы при нажатии на эту кнопку в итоге изменились запрошенные значения с сервера в переменной data

Tags: javascript

```
  let url = "https://gorest.co.in/public-api/posts?page=1";
  async function Load() {
    let response = await fetch(url);
    const data = await response.json();
    console.log(data);
  }
  Load();

  document.getElementById("btnF").addEventListener("click", function () {
    url = "https://gorest.co.in/public-api/posts?page=10";
  
  });
```

Comment: Не понимаю, в чём вопрос. "Запрошенные значения" не меняются что ли?

Comment: Вы меняете url, но не вызываете функцию, которая запрашивает данные

Comment: Надо просто добавить в событие `addEventListener` вызов функции `Load()`